# How do I update the SQL Server 2008 to include the studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I update the SQL Server 2008 to include the studio?

Here is what I currently have on my machine:

[image: [IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/sql%20server/sqlserver.png[/IMG]]

I assume I am supposed to clidk on "SQL Server Installation Center"

From there I get this window:

[image: [IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/sql%20server/sqlserver3.png[/IMG]]

and I assume I am supposed to click on the first item on the right side, "New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation". Is this right?

When I do this, I am asked to "Browse For Folder" but every folder I have picked so far has been denied. What do I do?

I have even resorted to uninstalling everything (via the OS Control Panel) and reinsatlling.  I still get o the point where it asks me for the location of the installation.  I install of a network, but it does not accept the location of the newtork when I give it.

Comment: Please tell us what the message asking for a folder is saying (or a screen shot) plus what the error says. You are in the right place in the installer to add management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try running setup.exe from the network directory where the SQL 2008 binaries are located.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the Express version of Microsoft SQL server?

If so you'll need to download the management tools from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961

Answer (score 0):

From your Installation menu, run the first option.  This will install some necessary setup files then allow you to select the instance you wish to modify.  On the Feature Selection page of the install, you will have the ability to just select the SSMS.